# replace sed command text inline

Tags: linux, bash, sed, replace

I have this file

file.txt

```
unknown@mail.com||unknown@mail.com||
unknown@mail2.com||unknown@mail2.com||
unknown@mail3.com||unknown@mail3.com||
unknown@mail4.com||unknown@mail4.com||
unknownpass
unknownpass2
unknownpass3
unknownpass4
```

How can I use the `sed` command to obtain this:

```
unknown@mail.com|unknownpass|unknown@mail.com|unknownpass|
unknown@mail2.com|unknownpass2|unknown@mail2.com|unknownpass2|
unknown@mail3.com|unknownpass3|unknown@mail3.com|unknownpass3|
unknown@mail4.com|unknownpass4|unknown@mail4.com|unknownpass4|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/\n[^|\n]*$/!ba;s/||\([^|]*\)||\(\n.*\)*\n\(.*\)$/|\3|\1|\3|\2/;P;D' file
```

Slurp the first part of the file into pattern space and one of the replacements, substitute, print and delete the first line and then repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this does use `sed` anyway:

```
{ sed -n 5,\$p file.txt; sed 4q file.txt; }  | awk 'NR<5{a[NR]=$0; next}
        {$2=a[NR-4]; $4=a[NR-4]} 1' FS=\| OFS=\|
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk 'BEGIN   {FS=OFS="|"}
     NR==FNR {if(NF==1) a[++c]=$1; next} 
     NF>4    {$2=a[FNR]; $4=$2; print}' file{,}
```

a two pass algorithm, caches the entries in the first round and inserts them into the empty fields, assumes the number of items match.

Here is another approach with one pass, powered by `tac` wrapped `awk`

```
tac file | 
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} 
     NF==1 {a[++c]=$1} 
     NF>4  {$2=a[c--]; $4=$2; print}' | 
tac
```

Answer (score 0):

I would combine the related lines with `paste` and reshuffle the elements with `awk` (I assume the related lines are exactly half a file away):

```
n=$(wc -l < file.txt)
paste -d'|' <(head -n $((n/2)) file.txt) <(tail -n $((n/2)) file.txt) |
awk '{ print $1, $6, $3, $6, "" }' FS='|' OFS='|'
```

Output:

```
unknown@mail.com|unknownpass|unknown@mail.com|unknownpass|
unknown@mail2.com|unknownpass2|unknown@mail2.com|unknownpass2|
unknown@mail3.com|unknownpass3|unknown@mail3.com|unknownpass3|
unknown@mail4.com|unknownpass4|unknown@mail4.com|unknownpass4|
```